# Debugging .cs file called from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2017

I have a Default.aspx that is defined like this and which I debug using Chrome (which is started from within VS2017 by clicking "Show in browser (Google Chrome)".

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="DevelopmentWithADot.AspNetSpeechSynthesizer.Test.Default" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="DevelopmentWithADot.AspNetSpeechSynthesizer" Namespace="DevelopmentWithADot.AspNetSpeechSynthesizer" tagPrefix="web" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="System.Speech, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" Namespace="System.Speech" TagPrefix="web" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script>

        function onSpeak(text)
        {
            //document.getElementById('synthesizer').speak(text);
            var nSynth = document.getElementById('synthesizer');

            if (nSynth == null)
            {
                debugger; //In internet explorer debugger will be hit directly (if you put a breakpoint). In google chrome, debugger will be hit if the developper tools is open.
                alert('Synthesizer is null!');
            }

            nSynth.speak(text);// I would like to debug what's going on here, but VS doesn't step into my breakpoints in "SpeechSynthesizer.cs"
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
    <div>
        <web:SpeechSynthesizer runat="server" ID="synthesizer" Age="Adult" Gender="Male" Culture="en-US" Rate="0" Volume="100" />
        <input type="text" id="text" name="text"/>
        <input type="button" value="SpeakIt" onclick="onSpeak(this.form.text.value)"/>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I would now like to debug what's going on in SpeechSynthesizer.cs (because I don't hear any output, and I would like to find out why).

So the first thing that came to my mind was that I need to step into SpeechSynthesizer.cs which is defined like this:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Speech.Synthesis;
using System.Threading;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

namespace DevelopmentWithADot.AspNetSpeechSynthesizer
{
    [ConstructorNeedsTag(false)]
    public class SpeechSynthesizer : HtmlGenericControl, ICallbackEventHandler
    {
        private readonly System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer synth = new System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer();

        public SpeechSynthesizer() : base("audio")
        {
            this.Age = VoiceAge.NotSet;
            this.Gender = VoiceGender.NotSet;
            this.Culture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
            this.VoiceName = String.Empty;
            this.Ssml = false;
        }

        [DefaultValue("")]
        public String VoiceName { get; set; }

        [DefaultValue(100)]
        public Int32 Volume { get; set; }

        [DefaultValue(0)]
        public Int32 Rate { get; set; }

        [TypeConverter(typeof(CultureInfoConverter))]
        public CultureInfo Culture { get; set; }

        [DefaultValue(VoiceGender.NotSet)]
        public VoiceGender Gender { get; set; }

        [DefaultValue(VoiceAge.NotSet)]
        public VoiceAge Age { get; set; }

        [DefaultValue(false)]
        public Boolean Ssml { get; set; }

        protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            AsyncOperationManager.SynchronizationContext = new SynchronizationContext();

            var sm = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page);
            var reference = this.Page.ClientScript.GetCallbackEventReference(this, "text", String.Format("function(result){{ document.getElementById('{0}').src = result; document.getElementById('{0}').play(); }}", this.ClientID), String.Empty, true);
            var script = String.Format("\ndocument.getElementById('{0}').speak = function(text){{ {1} }};\n", this.ClientID, reference);

            if (sm != null)
            {
                this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), String.Concat("speak", this.ClientID), String.Format("Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(function() {{ {0} }});\n", script), true);
            }
            else
            {
                this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), String.Concat("speak", this.ClientID), script, true);
            }

            base.OnInit(e);
        }

        protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Attributes.Remove("class");
            this.Attributes.Remove("src");
            this.Attributes.Remove("preload");
            this.Attributes.Remove("loop");
            this.Attributes.Remove("autoplay");
            this.Attributes.Remove("controls");

            this.Style[HtmlTextWriterStyle.Display] = "none";
            this.Style[HtmlTextWriterStyle.Visibility] = "hidden";

            base.OnPreRender(e);
        }

        public override void Dispose()
        {
            this.synth.Dispose();

            base.Dispose();
        }

        #region ICallbackEventHandler Members

        String ICallbackEventHandler.GetCallbackResult()
        {

            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                this.synth.Rate = this.Rate;
                this.synth.Volume = this.Volume;
                this.synth.SetOutputToWaveStream(stream);

                if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.VoiceName) == false)
                {
                    this.synth.SelectVoice(this.VoiceName);
                }
                else
                {
                    this.synth.SelectVoiceByHints(this.Gender, this.Age, 0, this.Culture);                  
                }

                if (this.Ssml == false)
                {
                    this.synth.Speak(this.Context.Items["data"] as String);
                }
                else
                {
                    this.synth.SpeakSsml(this.Context.Items["data"] as String);
                }

                return (String.Concat("data:audio/wav;base64,", Convert.ToBase64String(stream.ToArray())));
            }
        }

        void ICallbackEventHandler.RaiseCallbackEvent(String eventArgument)
        {
            this.Context.Items["data"] = eventArgument;
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

However, neither Google Chrome nor VS2017 let me step into SpeechSynthesizer.cs.

How could I debug what's going in there?

Thank you for any advice.

ps: This is the project hierarchy:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't *step into* it from the JavaScript side, but in VS2017 you can set a breakpoint on any of the constructors/methods of `SpeechSynthesizer` (or any other of your server-side classes). When you make the request from Chrome that uses that constructor/method, VS2017 will stop on the breakpoint, letting you step through the logic.

Comment: Thank you. Can you tell me where you'd put a breakpoint? I put breakpoints anywhere, but VS2017 doesn't break there. Perhaps I just put them in the wrong position?

Comment: I've added a screenshot of my project hierarchy to the posting. Does that reveal any reason why it might fail to hit my breakpoints? I don't have to upload the first project to the server, right? I guess I couldn't, but I wanted to ask anyway. Also, I can't attach the first project to chrome.exe, it says something like "Invalid in current situation".

Comment: @tmighty: You wouldn't normally use the server, you'd use the integrated "IIS Express" in VS2017. It should be simply: Set a breakpoint and press F5 to start the project (assuming you have a web project set as the startup project). With a standard config, that will launch your registered browser with the project's entry point, and when the code reaches a line you have a breakpoint on (in response to a request from the browser), it'll stop on the breakpoint.

Comment: Judging from the screenshot of my project hierarchy in my post, my project isn't a web project, right? At least I can't start it using F5, it says that a class library can't be started directly.

Comment: @tmighty: Why would a non-web project have `Default.aspx`, `Global.asax`, or `Web.config`? I think you need to take a step back and make sure you have things structured correctly.

Comment: Ahhh, thanks. You pointed me to my mistake. The web project wasn't the start project, I didn't notice that. Now it works, thank you.

Comment: In future, if you want to get debug point by crossing a javascript path, use Internet explorer.